# Sequence of binary numbers

Tags: python

I want to get a string that contains all binary numbers up to a given number.
At the output, I need a string.

```
bi = str(input())
n = int(bi , 2)

line = ""
for i in range(1 , n + 1):
    line += str(bin(i))[2:]

print(line)
```

My code does this, but I want to get a more beautiful and optimal solution.

For example:

input: `101`

output: `11011100101 (1 10 11 100 101)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this? it uses a generator expression for more concise and efficient looping, and you can customize how to print it when calling `join()`:

```
bi   = input() # for example, type 101
line = (bin(i)[2:] for i in range(1, int(str(bi), 2) + 1))

print(' '.join(line))
=> 1 10 11 100 101
```

Comment: Yes this is good. Is it possible to do this without using decimal numbers?

Comment: I'm not using decimal numbers, why do you say that?

Comment: I thought about it. int(str(bi), 2)

Comment: Those are not decimals, it's a conversion from an int in base 2 to an int in base 10, needed because range expects ints in base 10 but you're entering them in base 2.

Comment: `range` just expects `int`s, period. Only the *string* representation of an `int` requires any particular base.